# Is there any way to make Visual Studio 2010 stop starting my MVC projects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I have a Visual Studio 2010 Solution that contains a few library projectes, a few WPF projects and an ASP.NET MVC 3 project. When i start any project the MVC project get started in the development-server.
Is there some way to stop this behaviour?

**Edit:**
I just checked to make sure I´m to doing too much wrong. If you start a new solution with a console/whatever project and add an mvc3 project, everytime you start the console project the mvc project gets started as well.
Not sure if this is buggy or an intended feature, but it is kind of strange that the behaviour is so different from normal projects.

Comment: do you mean MVC project gets `built` when you start other projects?

Comment: no, i mean i start a wpf project and for some reason dev-server starts up with my mvc project that has no dependency on any of the other projects

Comment: @LDomagala check your solution properties. You may have selected multiple start up projects option

Comment: It's not just MVC projects. When you start the debugger *any* web project in your solution, whether or not it's in the current configuration, will have it's web server started.

Comment: @ChrisF is there a reason for this?

Comment: I don't know - now you've raised the question I've realised that this must be what's behind the situation I've got at work where our unit test project's web server gets started when we start the main project. I'm interested in knowing the answer too!

Comment: @LDomagala - You asked if there a reason for this. There is a reason. When you start debugging, VS makes sure that all binaries compiled up to date and ready for debugging. Suppose you have a web site that hosts a web service and a WPF client application. If VS didn't start development web server, you would not be able to test WPF client. You can argue that you would just set two startup project, both WPF and web service. With this reasoning you would need to set startup for each referenced library too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need MVC project for certain period of time, you can unload it (Right-click on the project and select `Unload project`).

Another option is to select local IIS as a web server (If you have it installed). This way it won't start development server.

Answer (score 0):

You can always choose another project as the default project to start up. You can right-click on the project and set as startup project.

Comment: I believe the question is not about start-up project. Development server will start, no matter which project is set as startup. Question states `When i start any project the MVC project get started`, which implies that another project is set as start-up.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your web projects are set to use local IIS rather than the Visual Studio Development server. Unlike the development server, IIS doesn't do anything with a new build until you actually try to load a page.